# comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter system object memory inefficiency

Tags: matlab

I'm using raised cosine transmit filter system object, and when I look at task manager at memory section, I see that after I pass a 1GB variable through the filter, the memory is increased by 2GB. i.e. 1GB is the output variable of the step function, and another 1GB "hidden" somehow in the hTxFilter system object. In "somehow" I mean that when I write "whos hTxFilter" in the command line, I see that the object uses 112 bytes, but when I clear the filter ("clear hTxFilter"), suddenly 1GB memory is free.

Code:

```
x = ones(round(1024^2/8),1);
whos x; % x weights 1MB
hTxFilt = comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter('FilterSpanInSymbols',20,'OutputSamplesPerSymbol',1024);
y=step(hTxFilt,x);
whos y hTxFilt; % y weights 1GB, hTxFilt weights 112 bytes
```

When I look at Task Manager, the memory was increased by 2GB instead of just 1GB (if I neglect the 1MB of x). When I clear hTxFilt, the memory is decreased by 1GB.

My question is, why hTxFilt "hides" 1GB in its object? I get that it's a filter, and a filter requires memory of some samples, but it's of filter span order (20) and not 125,000,000 samples??
What do I miss?

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: I'd say it is some form of preallocation, but since I do not know the function Im not sure.

Comment: First of all, if that's the case, why the "whos" command says the the hTxFilt system object "weighs" 112 bytes and not 1GB?
Second, since the filter memory is about 20 symbols, there is no reason it would keep the entire previous outcome in the memory. It needs only the last 20 symbols at maximum which weighs much less than 1GB...

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. In the Windows task manager -> resource monitor there's this thing called 'standby' memory. This is basically memory which is *reserved* for immediate use, but not in use already.